# Navigate to a certain tab on a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

In an objective-C Xcode project, I have currently set 5 different ViewControllers to 5 different tabs on a tab bar (a, b, c, d, e).  Whenever I try to navigate back to this tab bar controller from a view in my app other than a-e, I can only navigate to the "a" view of the TabBarVC (the first view).  How can I navigate to say the c view of this tab bar from a different view?

Comment: After navigating to your 'a' view of the tab bar use selectedIndex to move to 'c' tab

Answer (score 0):

You should navigate to `TabBarVC` passing parameter `initialIndex` telling which tab should be presented. Then override `viewWillAppear(_:)` method and set `selectedIndex` to `initialIndex` (`0..<numberOfControllers`) to set initially selected tab.

```
class TabBarVC: UITabBarController {

    ...

    var initialIndex: Int?

    ...

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if let initialIndex = initialIndex, let count = self.viewControllers?.count, initialIndex < count {
            self.initialIndex = nil
            self.selectedIndex = initialIndex
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using segue, this can be done in source controller in:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

Otherwise, just set `initialIndex` before presenting controller.